# How can I delete measurements within a time range for a given RP?

Tags: influxdb

## Question

Is it possible to delete measurement data using a time range, For a specific Retention Policy?

`DELETE 
FROM "SensorData"."Quarantine"./.*/ 
WHERE "time" >= '2018-02-28T02:26:08.0000000Z' 
AND "time" <= '2018-02-28T02:27:08.0000000Z'`

Is our current attempt at a query, to drop all data between a time period, however Delete doesn't appear to be happy to have a database or a retention policy listed.

---

## Possible XY Problem

The reason (I suspect it's an unsolved XY problem) (see [github://influxdata/influxdb#8088](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8088)) (This is step 3. below)

We have a Database called SensorData , that has a primary buffer default retention policy of 30d so we don't run out of disk space.

However, if the sensors register an 'exceedance' we have a requirement that requires us to keep that data, + an hour either side, for evidence. We call this Quarantine.

We have so far implemented this as a retention policy called Quarantine.

So we have Primary and Quarantine, and possibly in the future, some sort of high freq retention policy that might be down sampled to Primary.

The XY problem is, "How do you transaction-ally copy/move/change the retention policy on some recorded data in Influx?"

Our solution (after failing to find one)

Was,

e.g.

1. Create a temp db, named such as to uniquely identify an in progress quarantine operation.

   `create "TempDB"+"_Quarantine_"+startUnixTime+"_"+"endUnixTime"`
2. Copy the data from Primary to tempdb

   `Copy Primary -> TempDB`

**3. delete the data from primary**

```
   `Delete Primary`
```

4. Copy data to Quarantine

   `Copy TempDB -> Quarantine`
5. Drop TempDB

   `Drop TempDB`

This would allow rollback for a failed operation, or rollback/resume in the case of a crash.

Comment: Pardon me if I misunderstood your problem, but why are you trying to drop data for a retention policy, if it will drop it after a specified duration lasts anyway?
Your "Primary" RP will delete all the data in 30 days and if you need to preserve some data you can just copy it into "Quarantine".

Comment: We need to be able to change the retention policy at will for given data ranges. Some initial investigation by another developer was deleting the data first before reinserting, but copy or overwrite may be better. I think it may have had to do with wanting the operations to be transactional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying Database and retention policy is not supported via InfluxQL. I hope it will be in the future or in IFQL.

For now I would recommend to use a different measurement for the aggregated data.

Comment: That's a good suggestion re: the aggregated data, it's probably better in the long run as well to know explicitly what data you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the retention policy on some data range, I suggest just copying such data range into another retention policy:

```
USE "SensorData"

SELECT *
INTO "Quarantine"."MeasurementName" 
FROM "Primary"."MeasurementName" 
WHERE "time" >= '2018-02-28T02:26:08.0000000Z' 
    AND "time" <= '2018-02-28T02:27:08.0000000Z'
```

The data will be deleted from `"Primary"."MeasurementName"` as usual after duration specified for `"Primary"` RP ends (30 days), while the copied range will be preserved in `"Quarantine"` RP.

And if you want to delete the data from primary *immediately* what can try to do is next:

```
USE "SensorData"."Primary"

DELETE 
FROM "MeasurementName"
WHERE "time" >= '2018-02-28T02:26:08.0000000Z' 
    AND "time" <= '2018-02-28T02:27:08.0000000Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Chronograf was being really funky with parsing the query, causing a lot of confusion.

Influx (as of 1.4) does not have the ability to delete data for a specific retention policy, and Chronograf did not have the ability to parse the delete command without a database specified.

What ended up working, was (via an API) calling

`DELETE FROM /.*/ WHERE "time" >= '2018-02-28T02:26:08.0000000Z' AND "time" <= '2018-02-28T02:27:08.0000000Z'`

The database isn't specified, as it was specified elsewhere in the API.

Expected to be equivalent to calling `use SensorData` on the line before or in the CLI.

So for now the workaround is to just delete the data for all RP and hope you don't need a High Frequency Data retention policy in the future.